# ProgressDialog in Android not appearing (incorrect thread handling?)

Tags: android, runnable

I am trying to implement a radio player (using shoutcast streams) for android. What I want to do is, while the radio stream loads in the player, the UI displays a spinning wheel animation. On successful loading (as soon as the song starts playing) the animation disappears.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
PlayStopStreamingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Thread initializer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Looper.myLooper();
        Looper.prepare();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RadioPlayerActivity.this, "", "Selecting Radio Station",
            true);
        JukefoxApplication.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            radioPlayerEventListener.onPlayStopStreamingButtonClicked();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
          }
        });
      }
    });
    initializer.start();

  }
});
```

I don't get any spinning animation. I am almost certain that my mistake lies in incorrect handling of threads. If someone could out the correct way, I would be grateful.

EDIT, this seems to work:

```
    PlayStopStreamingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RadioPlayerActivity.this, "", "Selecting Radio Station", true);

            Thread initializer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    radioPlayerEventListener.onPlayStopStreamingButtonClicked();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            initializer.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think you dismiss it very fast, and that is why you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show progress dialog on UI thread, see below:

```
PlayStopStreamingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Thread initializer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Looper.myLooper();
        Looper.prepare();

        RadioPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RadioPlayerActivity.this,
                                     "", "Selecting Radio Station", true);
            }
        });

        JukefoxApplication.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            radioPlayerEventListener.onPlayStopStreamingButtonClicked();

            RadioPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
             });

      }
    });
    initializer.start();

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the runOnUiThread bit. However, meanwhile I have also implemented a solution that works (adding that as another answer, if there is anything wrong with it please tell me). Thanks for your time and effort.